# Hdd disconnects after some time randomly

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

My HDD sometimes disconnects and could not be used. Sometimes when I turn on computer there is only one HDD in boot screen and sometimes it becomes unaccessible after some time while using it.

When it's not recognized I can hear strange repetitive sound.

Sometimes plugging it to different port in motherboard helps. Sometimes flipping it upside down(it's a 2.5" in a desktop PC) helps.

Any suggestions where to start for searching problem?

Comment: Download a utility such as [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) that can run S.M.A.R.T diagnostics on the drive to see if it is failing.

Comment: HDDs that makes strange sounds normally are failing HDDs

Comment: I hope you have backups

Comment: Your hard drive is probably about to fail get a new one **NOW!**